# Python: How to extract decimal value out of a string, when a specific letter equals the decimal place? Example SG0P01, I want to make 0.01

Tags: python, string, replace, decimal

I have a string `SG0P01`, and I want to convert it to a decimal `0.01`, the `P` is the decimal place. I am not sure how to do this. I have tried using .replace, re, etc but cant figure it out.

```
string = "SG0P01"
dec = string.replace("P",".")
```

This results in `SG0.01`, now I just need to get rid of the `SG`, I tried using `re.sub('\D','',dec)` but that removes the decimal as well. Is there a way to preserve the decimal, or just do this entire thing in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

```py
import re

x = "SG0P01"
print(float(re.sub(r"SG\dP", "", x))/100)
```

```
0.01
```

> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsLmiR/1)

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert it to string is iterate over individual characters, check them if they are digits or `.` and join them:

```py
s = "SG0P01"

s = "".join(ch for ch in s.replace("P", ".") if ch.isdigit() or ch == ".")
print(float(s))
```

Prints:

```
0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the string with the decimal first and then replace the `P`. After that the correct string can be converted to a `float`:

```
import re

string = 'SG0P01'
number = float(re.search('\d+P\d+', string)[0].replace("P","."))
print(number)
```

Output:

```
0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex rule such as `SG0P(\d+)` you target the digit**s** after the term `SG0P` and add a `.` in front of it, for the cast to float.

```
import re
s = 'SG0P01'

s = re.sub(r'SG0P(\d+)', r'.\1', s)
s = float(s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the prefix will always be `SG` (or any two-character sequence), you can do this:

```py
dec = string[2:].replace("P",".")
```

If the prefix can be of arbitrary length and you know you that the decimal proxy `P` will always have at least one digit before and after, you can do this:

```py
import re
dec = re.search(r'\d+P\d+', string)[0].replace("P",".")
```

Explanation:

- the regex pattern `r'\d+P\d+'` matches one or more digits followed by `P` followed by one or more digits
- [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [`match object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) and using [`[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__) gets the 0'th group in the match object, which is `0P01` in your example
- [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a string with all occurrences of `P` replaced by `.`, which is `0.01` in your example.